# Magento 2 - How to create a custom module with admin config?

Tags: magento2, module, admin

How could I create a simple module to Magento 2 with admin configuration, like Porto theme or Amasty modules?

**Store > Configuration**

Comment: Are you asking  how to make your module's configuration in store->configuration?

Comment: @Neo yes, I added on the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Your Custome Module system.xml looks like This

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="yourid" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>YourModuleName</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="helloworld" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Your Tab Label</label>
            <tab>tabname</tab>
            <resource>your_modulename::yourmodule_configuration</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Flush Magento Cache**

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Getting Values Of Configuration**

Create Helper Class

```
<?php

namespace Your\namespace\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $objectManager;

    const XML_PATH_HELLOWORLD = 'helloworld/';



    public function __construct(Context $context,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->storeManager  = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
        );
    }


    public function getGeneralConfig($code, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_HELLOWORLD . $code, $storeId);
    }


}
```

Getting Values Of Configuration Using Helper Class

```
$helper = $this->objectManager->create('Your\namespace\Helper\Data');
echo $helper->getGeneralConfig('enable');
echo $helper->getGeneralConfig('display_text');
```

**Magento2 system.xml provides below fields type**

```
checkbox,
checkboxes,
column,
date,
editablemultiselect,
editor,
fieldset,
file,
gallery,
hidden,
image,
imagefile,
label,
link,
multiline,
multiselect,
note,
obscure,
password,
radio,
radios,
reset,
select,
submit,
text,
textarea,
time
```

You Can Find More About system.xml [Here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

When you have to make configuration in admin you have to make a `system.xml` in your module's `etc/adminhtml` and a `config.xml` to define their default values.

You can read more on this in this [tutorial](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/3169-2/)..

Answer (score 0):

I was having hard time using

```
return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,$storeId);
```

in my helper that extended AbstractHelper.

Was getting error in

> /var/log/httpd/error_log.log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /var/www/html/myproject/app/code/My/Customer/Helper/Data.php:170
```

Until I used the following

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $val = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue($config_path);
```

where `$config_path` was something like `dev/debug/template_hints`

Hope this helps someone like me.