# How to Disable Module on the basis of configuration Values in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7

I have created a New module in **Magneto 2** Which is Working well Now I want to control the status of the module on the bases of system Configuration setting

How can I do this?

I have already created a Field for status enable/disable in my `system.xml`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

syetm.xml file add custom filed for module configuration **system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="mytab" translate="label" sortOrder="500">
        <label>My Custom Extensions</label>
    </tab>

    <section id="custom_module" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>My Custom Module</label>
        <tab>mytab</tab>
        <resource>My_Module::config_my_module</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enable Module</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field> 
        </group>
  </section>
</system>
</config>
```

custom helper to check module enable / disable based on system configuration **My\Module\Helper\Data**

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
   const MODULE_ENABLE = "custom_module/general/enable";

   public function getDefaultConfig($path)
   {
       return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
   }

   public function isModuleEnabled()
   {
       return (bool) $this->getDefaultConfig(self::MODULE_ENABLE);
   }
 }
```

Block to get module configuration value **My\Module\Block\Product\View**

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Block\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
   /**
     * @var \My\Module\Helper\Data
   */
   protected $_dataHelper;

 /**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \My\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \My\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function canShowBlock()
{
    return $this->_dataHelper->isModuleEnabled();
}
}
```

template file display content based on the return value from block

```
<?php if ($block->canShowBlock()): ?>
   <h1> My Mdule content </h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That what i exactly need... THank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the backend configuration with the help of system.xml .In your module include the file system.xml in your etc folder. You can create a section in backend that can contains all the configuration you need to control from backend.

You can use below links for getting some idea and work accordingly

[Magento 2 - add Enable / Disable field for custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203535/magento-2-add-enable-disable-field-for-custom-module)

[Add module Enable/disable functionality in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257852/add-module-enable-disable-functionality-in-magento-2)

[Magento 2 - How to create a custom module with admin config?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168232/magento-2-how-to-create-a-custom-module-with-admin-config)